ROS2 command not found after Cmake upgrade - Ubuntu 20.04 focal & ros2 foxy
Before I was using ros2 foxy normally, but today I have to upgrade the cmake to a higher version, so I use sudo apt remove --purge --auto-remove cmake to remove the current cmake version and to install the latest version using sudo apt install cmake.
After I finished installing the cmake, now I can not use any command from ros2, even though I have sourced the installation environment. I have also check if the ROS2 were installed: echo $ROS_DISTRO, and it outputs 'foxy'. $ROS_VERSION: '2' (see screenshot).

What else can do to bring back all the features, or should I just reinstalled it. If I reinstall it, do I have to upgrade my cmake again ?

Your screenshot doesn't seem to match the text. Should the screenshot show the output of echo $ROS_DISTRO?
